# git merging "strategy" for common feature in different feature branches

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging

Suppose I have current situation in our git repo.

```
       -----qa_infra   
     /
dev-------
    \     \----- feature1
     \   
      ----------feature2
```

There is dev and two feature branches branched-out from dev.

Now there is infrastructure change ( for test running ) in branch "qa_infra" that really needed for both feature1 and feature2 before they merge back to dev.

the question is, what will be right merge-in strategy for such case?

Comment: If you can, check out dev, make the change there, possibly by separating it out of qa_infra, merge into all relevant branches. Otherwise, merge qa_infra into both feature branches. There are some inbetweens here as well, but I suspect you quickly can confirm if any of these solutions can work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

1. Merge `qa_infra` back to dev.
2. Merge dev in `feature1` and `feature2`.
3. Merge features in `dev` once they are ready.

Doing it like this has the following benefits, imho:

- The developer who did the `qa_infra` changes does not need to know about the features and has to resolve only merge conflicts with `dev` (if there are any). Most likely the will be conflicts about the `qa_infra` adjustments, which he is the expert in.
- The developers of the feature branches can decide when to merge the changes from `dev` in their feature branch. They can merge immediately or once their branch is finished or in between, whenever they want. As a developer I would really appreciate this, since I could finish my current logical step first and then deal with merging and possible conflicts.
- The merge conflicts (in case they occur) can be solved in small incremental steps, by the developers who likely know the most about the given conflict.
- Bonus: This is also [git-flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) compliant ;)